# How to remove Firefox orange microphone/webcam indicator from the top of the screen?

Tags: firefox, indicator

Firefox places this annoying indicator in the top of the screen when it is capturing video or sound from my computer.

[image]

It stays there even if I change to another window.

A Reddit post ([How do I remove this microphone indicator?](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/78pjz1/how_do_i_remove_this_microphone_indicator/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)) suggests using this `userChrome.css`:

```css
#webrtcIndicator {
  display: none;
}
```

However that does not work for me: The indicator is still up there, unchanged. **How can I get rid of it?**

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Navigate to your Firefox profile directory. If you do not know what it is:

- In Firefox, go to `Help > Troubleshooting Information`
- The directory is listed in `Profile Directory`.

2. Create the directory `chrome` in it.
3. Inside the `chrome` directory just created, create the file `userChrome.css` with these contents:

```css
#webrtcIndicator {
  display: none;
}
```

4. Enter `about:config` in Firefox address bar. Accept the prompt to be cautious.
5. Type `userprof` in the search field.
6. Switch the option `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` (you can double-click it to switch or click `Toggle` button).
7. Restart Firefox.

I tested this on GNU/Linux, but I have no reason to believe this would be an operating system specific solution.

Steps 5 to 7, which I found in [How to Create a userChrome.css File](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html#aboutconfig), are necessary for a Firefox version >= 69.

Comment: Is there a way to get back this icon of firefox ?

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. It's a shame firefox pushes this kind of widgets, as if people want more in-your-face elements that are hard to remove. SMH.

Answer (score 17):

For anyone finding this question through search engines, there's a **much** easier way now.

First, go to `about:config` and look for the key `privacy.webrtc.legacyGlobalIndicator`, and set it to `false`.

Now, "search" for the (non-existent) key `privacy.webrtc.hideGlobalIndicator`. Since it doesn't exist, you'll be allowed to create it. Choose the `boolean` type, and set it to `true`.

Restart Firefox and that pesky icon will be gone!

Comment: This solution seems to be more up to date and works in Firefox 92.0.1. It should be marked as accepted in place of the previous answer.

Comment: Note: I just had to set `privacy.webrtc.legacyGlobalIndicator` to `false`, didn't need `privacy.webrtc.hideGlobalIndicator`.